# Query for Opens last month

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I would like to write a query to find subscribers who opened emails sent from journey builder in the previous month, but this query returns 0 records. May I know where I did wrong, please? Thank you.

```
Select
j.JobID,
j.EmailName,
j.DeliveredTime as SendTime,
o.EventDate as OpenTime,
s.EmailAddress,
s.SubscriberKey
from [_Job] j
join [_Open] o
on j.JobID = o.JobID
join [_Subscribers] s
on o.SubscriberID = s.SubscriberID
where
o.IsUnique = 1 and
DATEPART(Y,o.EventDate) > DATEPART(Y,DATEADD(M, -1, GETDATE())) and
j.EmailID = 47493
```

Comment: you will likely wanna check out the Journey and Journey Activity DataViews:  Journey (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_journey.htm&type=5) Journey Activity (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_journey_activity.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can try replacing:

```
join [_Subscribers] s
```

with:

```
join ent._ListSubscribers s
```

If still not working, you may compare both years and months like instead of:

```
DATEPART(Y,o.EventDate) > DATEPART(Y,DATEADD(M, -1, GETDATE())) and
```

this:

```
DATEPART(m, o.EventDate) > DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE())) and
DATEPART(yyyy, o.EventDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE())) and /*/ if still in the same year /*/
```